# How to perform automated installation of RedMon with Ghostscript

Tags: c++, qt, batch-file, ghostscript, redmon

Following the steps of this article: http://mbmcclelland.blogspot.com.br/2012/11/creating-free-pdf-printer-in-windows-7.html, I installed successfully a virtual printer which prints to a PDF file, but all the process has done manually. I want some way to automatized install that printer with a batch file or Qt/c++, most especifically do the steps 2 and 4 of the article (Create the Virtual PDF Printer using a Windows Driver and Configure your Virtual PDF printer to use Ghostscript). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly do it with a C/C++ program, by calling the relevant Windows API routines (AddPrinter and friends eg AddPort, AddMonitor etc). I doubt you can do it with a batch file, I have no idea if Qt is powerful enough.